# Specifying and plotting PCA site symbols according to zone

Tags: r, pca, vegan

I'm creating a PCA in the example below, I know to to get the plot to vary the symbol according to another variable (I've just used a set of zones from 1 to 5 for example).

I would like to know how to also specify the plotting symbol for each zone as I don't like the default.

Here's my example:

```
## load vegan

require("vegan")

## load the Dune data
data(dune)

## run pca
dune_pca <- rda(dune)

## create zones for e.g. 
zone <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)

## plot blank PCA and add sites with 
## symbol varying accoring to zone
plot(dune_pca, type = "n", scaling = 3)
points(dune_pca, display = "sites", scaling = 3, pch = zone)
```

Comment: `help("points")` gives you a list of symbols and their corresponding numbers. Just make sure your zones take those numbers (i.e. if you want a full black trinagle for your first zone, use 17 instead of 1 in your zone vector).

Comment: thanks for your help, I hadn't realised that pch was taking my zone numbers literally as the symbol integers rather than the default first 5 symbols - that's useful to know. Is there a quick way that I could replace the zone numbers with the desired symbol number?

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(factor(zone,levels=1:5,labels=c(12,14,17,21,22))))` (with random pchs number as labels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a vector of the characters I want and then subset this by zone

```
zone_pch <- c(16, 10, 3, 8, 2)
plot(dune_pca, type = "n", scaling = 3)
points(dune_pca, display = "sites", scaling = 3, pch = zone_pch[zone])
```